# Twitter API-Limit for the user timeline

Tags: twitter, tweepy

The [Twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) for the `user_timeline` REST API state, that you can retrieve up to 3200 Tweets (before any filters) from a user timeline, requesting 200 tweets per request.

When I use the [tweepy user_timeline](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.user_timeline) method with parameter `count=200`, i get for users other than the authenticated one less than 200 (in one example 82 tweets).
Using `max_id` with the biggest id of the returned tweets (which should return the 200 before `max_id`) just returns an empty list.

Why can't i access any tweets before these 82 tweets?

Comment: Is it possible that the tweets you are not receiving are retweets? I haven't researched whether or not this could effect the outcome of tweets, so this could be useless information.

Comment: This could be possible, currently I cannot test the exact same scenario. Still I think should be able to get more tweets when the docs state I can get (using pagination) up to 3200.